# RAM configuration in HP Z-420

Tags: windows

I have an HP Z-420 workstation, it came with all RAM slots loaded with a total of 24GB DDR3 RAM.

One of the slots (#3) has gone bad, and now shows 18GB RAM total, I would like to load the ram slots with 4 modules of 1
8GB RAM, but I am not sure which slots to load, leaving slot #3 out.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Your question does not make sense.  If you only have 3 slots that work, you would fill those 3 slots, and not use the slot you have determine does not function.

Comment: Are you sure it's the slot and not the RAM itself?

Comment: Z420 model has 8x slots so if all were loaded originally that'd be 3GB modules (24GB/8-slots=3) so it will be assumed the user is installing new 8GB ram sticks, hopefully they will work with this model, [pg21 specs](http://h10032.www1.hp.com/ctg/Manual/c04205252.pdf) show should work

Comment: I think Robert is alluding to having pairs of slots populated - which used to be a requirement a while ago.

Comment: @Robert 76: Ramhound was confused because you didn't specify you were installing different memory that the original RAM, its still unclear if that is the case. More info is always helpful to those giving technical support/assistance

Comment: 24/8 would mean 4 GB sticks, which does no makes sense if the system is now only detecting 18 GB. Regardless the question does not have enough details.

Comment: Originally all 8 slots were filled with 4gb and 2 gb modules, now slot #3 is bad, so which 4 slots do I add new memory in 8 gb modules leaving 4 slots empty (to include slot #3 as one of the empty slots)/,

Comment: Why isn’t that information in the question body?

Comment: Using my answer can you not load those four 8GB RAM sticks in slots 1, 2, 4, 5 (skipping bad slot 3)? Is it giving you an error when you do that?

Answer (score 1):

1. Go to [support.hp.com](https://support.hp.com/us-en)
2. enter in your model
3. setup & user guides
4. look for 'Workstations Maintenance and Service Guide'. Here is link for your model, see pg98-99 & pg101: http://h10032.www1.hp.com/ctg/Manual/c04205252.pdf
   [image]

Put four 8GB sticks in slots 1, 2, (skip 3 as it's broken), 4, 5. Then in remaining slots (6, 7, & 8) put in the lower 4GB sticks. **Reference picture & manual above because the RAM slots are not visually in order/sequence, they jump around.**